# Ajax weird behavior in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

Here's the code I use to ajax more reviews:

```
function showMoreReviews(str) {
    var counter = Number($('#counter').val());
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("reviews").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    counter = counter + 10;
    $('#counter').attr({ value: counter });

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //document.getElementById("reviews").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $("#reviews").append("<div id='rnum" + counter + "'>" + xmlhttp.responseText + "</div>");
            $("#rnum" + counter).hide().fadeIn(800);
        }
    }

    console.log(str);
    console.log(counter);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/MoreReviewsAjax.asp?ml=" + str + "&c=" + counter, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It works fine in all browsers except in IE8.. Now here is the weird thing - the code will work if in IE8 I go to dev tools and start debugging for scripts. Otherwise it doesn't work.

PS I am using virtual PC and Windows XP w/ IE8 for IE8 tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `console.log()` calls are the problem.

You can add a cheap "polyfill" to your system:

```
if (!('console' in window)) {
  window.console = {
    log: function() {},
    dir: function() {},
    // whatever other console functions you use
  };
}
```

Those dummy functions won't do anything, but they'll keep IE from losing it's mind.

Comment: @N0ir When you don't have the developer console open, the `console` object is not defined and causes an error. (The decision to make it work that way was clearly made by the wrong person.)

Comment: I removed console.logs and it works now, thanks. Would have never thought of this... I guess its all about expirience